# Smallest overlapping circles containing unit circles in each section - Second arrangement

Tags: geometry, circles, symmetry, computational-geometry

This question is closely related to [the question that I posted yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4574632/smallest-overlapping-circles-containing-unit-circles-in-each-section). The simpler symmetry of this problem makes me think that this variation will be simpler to solve, so I suggest that anyone who is intrigued by the problems should start with this one.

One way of overlapping 3 circles looks like this:

[image]

**What is the smallest size** that these circles can have and still be large enough to accommodate a unit circle in each region?

With unit circles pictured for clarity and zoomed in, it's something like this (where circles that appear to be approximately tangent should indeed be perfectly tangent):

EDIT (improved picture now that I know the exact radius):

[image]

By pure physical manipulation of circles, it seems to me that the radius of the 3 circles may be a bit less than 15. But I'm having difficulty determining an exact answer. Any solutions--partial or complete--would be appreciated.

Note: in writing this I realized that I have made the implicit assumption that the smallest possible area covered by 3 circles meeting these requirements will be done with 3 equally sized circles. As proof of this claim, I offer these waving hands and some mumbled lines about symmetry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

In the "perfectly tangent" configuration, we have the red Pythagoras triangle and the blue equilateral triangle, which implies the red triangle is $30^\circ, 60^\circ,90^\circ$. Therefore $$r+1 = {2\over \sqrt{3}}(r-1)$$ and $r=7+4\sqrt{3}$

Comment: This is the correct result. You may want to add the reason why the red triangle has a straight edge.

Comment: Basically the unit circle has to be in the exact middle of the "eye" shape, because otherwise there will be room for making the big circles smaller. And this implies the unit circle is symmetric over the line connecting centers of two of the big circles

Comment: Why not promote that from a comment to part of the answer?

Comment: This is a really lovely answer, and I appreciate it.
Drawing the image was a bit tricky when I didn't know the circle sizes.  It was quite iterative. It turns out that "a bit less than 15" wasn't so far off... but 13.93 is a lot closer to 7+4√3. I'll use this to update my images.