# Smallest overlapping circles containing unit circles in each section - Fourth arrangement

Tags: geometry, circles, symmetry, computational-geometry

I hope people aren't too tired of these. I'm finding them to be really lovely.

This question is closely related to [a question that I posted recently](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4574632/smallest-overlapping-circles-containing-unit-circles-in-each-section).

Another way of overlapping 3 circles looks like this:

[image]

If we want to size these circles such that they are as small as possible yet still large enough for a unit circle to fit in each of the 7 regions, then we get a diagram like this:

[image]

The question then, is what are the radii of the circles?

In contrast to my previous posts... I have a proposed answer! But the exact answer is sufficiently inelegant that it has me wondering whether I got it right. My explanation is shown below.

The smaller circle in the middle has radius A. The other two circles have radius B.

[image]

1. EDIT *FALSE*: The red triangle must be a right triangle with legs B and hypotenuse $\sqrt{2}B$.
2. We can also say that the red hypotenuse has length 2B - 2(A-2).
3. The blue triangle gives us a right triangle using both A & B.

So we get these 2 equations:

- $\sqrt{2}B=2B-2(A-2)$
- $(B-1)^2=(A+1)^2+({\sqrt{2}\over2}B)^2$

Solving these equations gives exact answers that appear inelegant to me. So I question the result. But... the approximate answers are reasonably close to what I got just constructing the diagram. So perhaps the smaller circle, A, really is ${\sqrt{52\sqrt{2}+86}\over{2}}-{\sqrt{26\sqrt{2}+43}\over{2}}+{2\sqrt{2}}+{1\over2}≈5.178$

Confirmation that this seems valid or correction where it's not valid would be much appreciated.

Comment: The red triangle having a right triangle at the top seems not obvious to me and perhaps is wrong. I will take a closer look later when I have time.

Comment: Looks like there is only one equation on the blue triangle and the shape is not fixed. You need to optimize the total area based on that one single equation $(r+1)^2+(R+r-2)^2=(R-1)^2$ using Lagrange Multiplier method. The total area formula, however, does not seem trivial to me to be expressed using $R$ and $r$, as you need to subtract the middle eye shape.

Comment: You could express the area of the eye shape in terms of $R$ and $r$ with arccos function, which indeed has a nice derivative. This in theory should allow the Lagrange Multiplyer optimization to be completed. However the calculation is pretty intense, I will try if I will have time to do it.

Comment: Where you wrote $(+1)^2+(+−2)^2=(−1)^2$ is it not $(+1)^2+(-(−2))^2=(−1)^2$? I had that in one of my attempts as well.

Comment: You are surely correct about the red triangle not being a right triangle. I suspect that in fact it's not too far off from 90º... but there's no justification for my claim that it is exactly that.

Comment: Yes it was a typo.